# Trigger an action at a specific time using Trigger and Rules

Tags: 7, rules

I would like to run an action once a specific `$_SESSION` variable is set. In both Trigger and Rules, I do not find a description on how to do something like that. Can anybody help me, or at least hint at a website explaining this?

I am looking for an easy way to initiate a call at a specific time (think of as a Drupal alarm clock); my idea was to put the time in a `$_SESSION` variable and fire the alarm clock once `$_SESSION['alarm'] == strtotime("now")`.

In case that this should just not be possible: I would also be happy with a trigger that fires whenever I go on a certain page.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you interested in the $_SESSION variable? What is the bigger action you are trying to accomplish?

The easiest way to fire any event when a user visits a page in Drupal is too use [hook_menu](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) and create a custom callback.

If you are trying to fire an action at a specific time you can [setup a cron](http://drupal.org/cron) job to go off at the time you desire.  Drupal 7 core has a built in cron mechanism you can tell to go off at certain time increments /admin/config/system/cron . If you don't have access to your server to setup a cron job and want it to go off at a specific time once a day (ala an alarm clock)  you can use one of these modules [Advanced Cron Modules](http://groups.drupal.org/node/17072)

In order to respond to a cron job you can use hook_cron or using a cron trigger at "/admin/structure/trigger/system"

---

Comment: updated answer. let me know if that is what you were thinking.

Comment: Dear Acouch, thanks for your reply! This is indeed the right direction, and I had already experimented with hook_cron. However, I could not find out how to define the time (or time intervals) for cron to run. In the admin menu the smallest frequency is 1 hour, which is clearly not enough for me. I would rather need something like 1 min. I would be overly grateful if you could help me out with this one!

Comment: If you are able to create a crontab that is the best method. Most but not all hosts will allow you to do this. If not one of the advanced cron modules will allow you to set an exact time.